# change jquery mobile color swatch dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes

I want to change a jquery-mobile buttons color swatch dynamically with javascript, but I can't' find a way (except removing and adding all classes and event handlers, but that's to messy).
Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: I found another method to update the theme and wrote a blog post about it since I couldnt find what I wanted on stackoverflow. In case, anyone needs it : https://vshivam.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/dynamically-change-jquery-mobile-colour-swatch/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I did do something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/20/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/28/ (All form elements)

JS (might need minor tweaks to get what you want)

```
$('input[name=theme-options]').change(function() {
    var currentTheme = $('#home').attr('data-theme');
    var selectedTheme = $(this).val();

    alert('CT '+currentTheme+' ST '+selectedTheme);

    $('.ui-body-' + currentTheme).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme);    
    });

    $('.ui-btn-up-' + currentTheme).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-up-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-btn-up-' + selectedTheme);    
    });

    $('.ui-btn-down-' + currentTheme).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-down-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-btn-down-' + selectedTheme);    
    });

    $('#home').find('*[data-theme]').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('data-theme',selectedTheme);
    });

    $('#home').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
});
```

HTML (might need minor tweaks to get what you want)

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">             
            <p>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Choose a Theme:</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="theme-options" id="theme-option-a" value="a" checked="checked" data-theme="a" />
                        <label for="theme-option-a" data-theme="a">Theme A</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme-options" id="theme-option-b" value="b" data-theme="b" />
                        <label for="theme-option-b" data-theme="b">Theme B</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme-options" id="theme-option-c" value="c" data-theme="c" />
                        <label for="theme-option-c" data-theme="c">Theme C</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme-options" id="theme-option-d" value="d" data-theme="d" />
                        <label for="theme-option-d" data-theme="d">Theme D</label>

                        <input type="radio" name="theme-options" id="theme-option-e" value="e" data-theme="e" />
                        <label for="theme-option-e" data-theme="e">Theme E</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </p>

            <form action="#" method="get"> 

                <h2>Form elements</h2> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="name">Text Input:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  /> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label> 
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="search">Search Input:</label> 
                    <input type="search" name="password" id="search" value=""  /> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="slider2">Flip switch:</label> 
                    <select name="slider2" id="slider2" data-role="slider"> 
                        <option value="off">Off</option> 
                        <option value="on">On</option> 
                    </select> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="slider">Slider:</label> 
                    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  /> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
                        <legend>Choose as many snacks as you'd like:</legend> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-2a">Doritos</label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-3a">Fritos</label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-4a">Sun Chips</label> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
                        <legend>Font styling:</legend> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-6" id="checkbox-6" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-6">b</label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-7" id="checkbox-7" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-7"><em>i</em></label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-8" id="checkbox-8" class="custom" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox-8">u</label> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
                        <legend>Choose a pet:</legend> 
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label> 

                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label> 

                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label> 

                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
                        <legend>Layout view:</legend> 
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-c" value="on" checked="checked" /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-c">List</label> 
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-d" value="off" /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-d">Grid</label> 
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-e" value="other" /> 
                        <label for="radio-choice-e">Gallery</label> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label> 
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1"> 
                        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option> 
                        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option> 
                        <option value="express">Express: next day</option> 
                        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option> 
                    </select> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Your state:</label> 
                    <select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3"> 
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                        <option value="CA">California</option> 
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                        <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                    </select> 
                </div> 

                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <label for="select-choice-a" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label> 
                    <select name="select-choice-a" id="select-choice-a" data-native-menu="false"> 
                        <option>Custom menu example</option> 
                        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option> 
                        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option> 
                        <option value="express">Express: next day</option> 
                        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option> 
                    </select> 
                </div> 

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b"> 
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a"> 
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="d">Cancel</button></div> 
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </div> 
            </form> 
        </div><!--/content-primary -->        

        <div class="content-secondary"> 

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b"> 

                <h3>More in this section</h3> 

                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d"> 

                    <li data-role="list-divider">Form elements</li> 
                    <li><a href="docs-forms.html">Form basics</a></li> 
                    <li data-theme="a"><a href="forms-all.html">Form element gallery</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="texts/index.html">Text inputs</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-search.html">Search inputs</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-slider.html">Slider</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-switch.html">Flip toggle switch</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="radiobuttons/index.html">Radio buttons</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="checkboxes/index.html">Checkboxes</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="selects/index.html">Select menus</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-themes.html">Theming forms</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-all-native.html">Native form elements</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="forms-sample.html">Submitting forms</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="plugin-eventsmethods.html">Plugin methods</a></li> 

                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#showHideButton').click(function(){
 var j=0;        
 if(i%2 !=0){
 $('#passenger').find('tr.content').hide();
                             $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-d').addClass('ui-icon-u').trigger('create');;

            j=1;
        }
    else
        {
            $('#passenger').find('tr.content').show();
                             $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-u').addClass('ui-icon-d').trigger('create');;

                             j=1
        }
                             
    i = i+j;
});` Everything works but the icon doesn't changes.

Answer (score 20):

At least in 1.2.0 (1.2.0-rc1) its as simple as (probably it works in minor versions):

`$( "#myButton" ).buttonMarkup({theme: 'd'});`

not `.button('refresh')` needed

Comment: this should be the answer ... docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is:

```
//set button active
$(this).parent().addClass('ui-btn-active');
//set button inactive
$(this).parent().removeClass('ui-btn-active');
```

Adding the class 'ui-btn-active' to the parent will set the current button to active and change the data-theme to 'b'. This will not work for any arbitrary swatch though. So you may still need one of the longer solutions mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, looks like there is no way to simply change the theme swatch.

I hacked a simple function to exchange the color by regex:

```
$.fn.changeColorSwatch = function(theme, type) {
  if (!type) {
    type = 'theme';
  }
  var currentTheme = this.attr('data-' + type);
  if (!currentTheme) {
    currentTheme = 'c';
  }
  this.attr('data-' + type, theme);
  var regex = new RegExp('^ui-(.*)-' + currentTheme + '$');
  var classes = $.extend({}, this[0].classList);
  var i = classes.length;
  while (i--) {
    var match = classes[i].match(regex);
    if (match) {
      this.removeClass(match[0]);
      this.addClass('ui-' + match[1] + '-' + theme);
    }
  }
};
```

I know, it should use `jqmData` instead of `attr`, but the data-theme attribute wasn't changed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons need to have the parent element theme changed as well.

Add the following code to the end of the  $.fn.changeColorSwatch function

```
      if(this.attr('type') == 'button'){
      this.parent().changeColorSwatch(theme, type);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the button is defined as:

```
<button type="button" id="yourbutton">Hello</button>
```

Then this works the fastest:

```
$('#yourbutton').parent().find('.ui-btn-inner').css("background-color",yournewcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works perfectly !! :D

[Mikael Kindborg answer from Change data-theme in jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667603/change-data-theme-in-jquery-mobile/23577762#15585104)

```
$.mobile.changeGlobalTheme = function(theme)
    {
        // These themes will be cleared, add more
        // swatch letters as needed.
        var themes = " a b c d e";

        // Updates the theme for all elements that match the
        // CSS selector with the specified theme class.
        function setTheme(cssSelector, themeClass, theme)
        {
            $(cssSelector)
                    .removeClass(themes.split(" ").join(" " + themeClass + "-"))
                    .addClass(themeClass + "-" + theme)
                    .attr("data-theme", theme);
        }

        // Add more selectors/theme classes as needed.
        setTheme(".ui-mobile-viewport", "ui-overlay", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='page']", "ui-page-theme", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='header']", "ui-bar", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='listview'] > li", "ui-bar", theme);
        setTheme(".ui-btn", "ui-btn-up", theme);
        setTheme(".ui-btn", "ui-btn-hover", theme);
    };
```