# jQuery mobile dynamically added theme to page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a new page dynamically using jQuery mobile. I would like to now add the theme i.e.  `data-theme="a"` . Is there an easier way to do this? At the moment it looks like I will be added it to every div below.

```
 var newPage = $("<div data-role='page' id='" + v["id"] +
                "'><div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' " +
                "data-rel='back'>Back</a>" +
                "<h1>" + v["name"] + "</h1>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div data-role=content>" + pagecontent +
                "</div>" +
                "<div data-role='footer'>" +
                "<h4>" + v["name"] + "</h4>" +
                " </div>" +
                "</div>");


            // Append the new page info pageContainer
            newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
```

i.e. it would be good if there was something like this....

```
 newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer).theme('a');
```

Answer (score 5):

## Update - jQuery Mobile 1.4

There is a [bug in `.page()` widget](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8385) when using `.page({"theme"})` or `.page("option", "theme")`. It doesn't remove current theme class, however, it adds new theme class. Yet, new class doesn't override old class. So here is the fix.

```
(function($, undefined) {
  $.widget("mobile.page", $.mobile.page, {
    _setOptions: function(o) {
      if (o.theme !== undefined) {
        this.element
          .removeClass(function(i, c) {
            return (c.match(/\bui-page-theme-\w/g) || []).join(' ');
          })
          .addClass("ui-page-theme-" + o.theme);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

> **Note:** Default theme in jQuery Mobile is **"a"**.

---

To set theme for dynamically created pages, use `$('.selector').page({theme:'e'});` after you append pages and before you navigate to them using `$.mobile.changePage()`.

For a specific page:

```
$('.selector').page({theme:'e'});
```

For all pages:

```
$('[data-role=page]').page({theme:'e'});
```

---

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L6d9wxb2/)** - Updated with .page() fix

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works really great :D

[Mikael Kindborg answer from Change data-theme in jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667603/change-data-theme-in-jquery-mobile/23577762#15585104)

```
$.mobile.changeGlobalTheme = function(theme)
    {
        // These themes will be cleared, add more
        // swatch letters as needed.
        var themes = " a b c d e";

        // Updates the theme for all elements that match the
        // CSS selector with the specified theme class.
        function setTheme(cssSelector, themeClass, theme)
        {
            $(cssSelector)
                    .removeClass(themes.split(" ").join(" " + themeClass + "-"))
                    .addClass(themeClass + "-" + theme)
                    .attr("data-theme", theme);
        }

        // Add more selectors/theme classes as needed.
        setTheme(".ui-mobile-viewport", "ui-overlay", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='page']", "ui-page-theme", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='header']", "ui-bar", theme);
        setTheme("[data-role='listview'] > li", "ui-bar", theme);
        setTheme(".ui-btn", "ui-btn-up", theme);
        setTheme(".ui-btn", "ui-btn-hover", theme);
    };
```