# Dynamically changing hyperlink theme within jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile how does one dynamically change the theme of a hyperlink within a `controlgroup`. I have the `id` of the hyperlink but can not find a way of doing this.... I tried:

```
var ohyper= $("#myid");
ohyper.a({theme: 'b'});
```

I've Answer my own question.

The following piece of code will dynamically change any hyperlink's theme within a controlgroup in jquery mobile.

$( "#"+myid ).controlgroup({theme: 'b'});

I hope this will help anyone else with a similar question.

Comment: What do u mean by theme? Css?

Comment: in jquery mobile there are different themes that can be set for the page or control groups

Comment: I've answer my own quertion..code $( "#"+cbook_id ).controlgroup({theme: 'b'});

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of changing the theme would be as follows:

```
$(this).buttonMarkup({theme: 'b'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/HuWgs/
Maybe this is usefull to you: [change jquery mobile color swatch dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667603/change-data-theme-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: I tried that on my hyperlink id within the controlgroup and it did not work. then i tried my solution and that worked...

Comment: can you put your code in `jsfiddle.net` ? and see this http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/HuWgs/ it works